# Check if a variable is set in PHP

Tags: php, variables, isset

After 10 years of PHP programming, just now I found out that `isset()` is not good at all, according to [PHP `isset()` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), `isset()` returns false when variable 'is set' and has a `null` value.

Well, I was working with an array and I fixed this by `array_key_exists()`, just after about 2 hours of reading and testing codes.

but what to use for variables?

```
isset($var) || is_null($var)
```

This makes NOTICE when $var is not set...  empty() is completely in another world too. As I said, is_null() makes NOTICE on not set variables and returns true!!... Well, this one is out, too.

Comment: `isset($var) && !is_null($var)`. In your example, if `$var` isn't set, the `isset` will return `false` causing the `is_null` to be executed (throwing the notice). By using `&&`,  if `isset` returns `false`, the expression will return false immediately.

Comment: You are right, looks like I need to sleep :)... Well, I'm looking for a better  solution... In large apps we check for variables existence hundreds or thousands of times, isn't there a better solution than `isset($var) && !is_null($var)`... Also, it is not possible to define a function for this purpose. Because PHP shows errors if variable is not set, and sets null to variable if we pass by reference... Ah PHP!

Comment: @FirstOne empty() returns true on null, false, "" (empty string), 0 (integer zero), 0.0 (float zero), array() or [] (empty array), $var (variable declared but has no value), AND "0" !!! (an string containing zero character). Actually, it should not be used for checking for variable existence at all.

Comment: You forgot to describe what you want to achieve. [`isset($var)` is the same as `! is_null($var)`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (except for a notice thrown by `is_null()` when the variable does not exist). This means `isset($var) && ! is_null($var)` is the same as `isset($var)`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick guide on `is_null` and `empty` can be found [here](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/), I used to reference it quite a bit.

As you noted, `is_null` is a complainer.  The only way to test this without throwing a NOTICE is to check if the variable is set in the global vars array.  You can do this by testing as such:

```
// Is Set (to anything)
if(!(isset($var) || array_key_exists('var',get_defined_vars()))){ /* ... */ }
// Set and Null
if(!(is_null($var) || array_key_exists('var',get_defined_vars())))) { /* ... */ }

// Etc
```

The problem here is that you are using `get_defined_vars` and this has significant performance impacts, both in wall-time and memory usage, if over-used, and I would suggest it should just be used for debugging.

If you are interested in strictly `global` variables, you can use the `$GLOBALS` supervar.  However, this will not give you access to variables inside the scope of a function or method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/418162/1301994

If you are trying to avoid NOTICES to increase performance, this is not worth it, as the overhead for check is greater than the slight performance gains.

I guess it really matters what your goals are.  If you are working in an OOP fashion, then you should be able to tell fairly clearly if a variable is set or not in the scope of the method.  Otherwise, it would be best to not code in such a way that `undefined` and `NULL` behave differently.  If this is not possible, consider utilizing other flags to help you get around the use of `get_undefined_vars`.

Check below for a little more on the topic:

[Is var set to null same as undefined and how to check differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868652/is-var-set-to-null-same-as-undefined-and-how-to-check-differences/26869030)

Comment: This misses the case where the variable is a global. The correct condition is `(array_key_exists('var',get_defined_vars()) or array_key_exists('var',$GLOBALS)`